# GO flags not parsing properly

Tags: go

I have a very basic CLI app right now to play around with the `flag` library. It accepts two flags and simply prints the value to the terminal

```
$ ./hello --flag1 v1 --flag2 v2
v1
v2
```

If say I accidentally set `flag2`, but forget to provide the value, it *expectedly* displays an error message

```
$ ./hello --flag1 v1 --flag2
flag needs an argument: -flag2
Usage of ./hello:
  -flag1 string
        usage1 (default "value1")
  -flag2 string
        usage3 (default "value2")
```

But if I set `flag1`, not provide a value for it, and then set `flag2`, there is no error

```
$ ./hello --flag1 --flag2 v2
--flag2
value2
```

Seems odd to me that `flag1` would use the name of `flag2` as the value, not to mention `flag2` doesn't even get the value provided. I would expect the result to be an error message similar to when `flag2` was set and no value provided.

Is this a limitation of the library? Or is this a bug?

Is there someway to get it to parse properly or would I have to add my own custom parsing logic?

Minimum code to reproduce:

```golang
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    flag1 := flag.String("flag1", "value1", "usage1")
    flag2 := flag.String("flag2", "value2", "usage3")

    flag.Parse()

    fmt.Println(*flag1)
    fmt.Println(*flag2)
}
```

Comment: Can you make it into a golang playground running sample?

Comment: I pasted the sample code into a golang playground, but not sure how one would run it with arguments https://play.golang.org/p/9l9Xd6QyZGB

Comment: If the flag library interpreted every word starting with a dash or a double dash as flag, then you wouldn't be able to pass, for instance, a negative number as a value. What the flag library is doing is correct: if a flag is to be followed by an argument and you pass another flag instead of the argument, that flag *is* the argument.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. And I found that other CLIs also behave this way, but add in validation checks after the flags have been parsed to ensure the values are valid.

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly set it with `""` if you want `flag2` to be the empty string.

```
$ ./hello --flag1 v1 --flag2 ""
```

For your other question, when you specify the `flag1`, everything that comes after is the string value. So it doesn't sounds weird that when you use

```
$ ./hello --flag1 --flag2
```

Then the value of `flag1` is "flag2", since it is the same as you were write it like this:

```
$ ./hello --flag1="--flag2"
```

By the way, the type of flag you don't have to specify a value for is `bool`. It's enough to only specify the flag for it to be `true`.

Comment: The question was more about what happens if a user sets a flag, but accidentally forgets to provide a value for it. Logically speaking, it does make sense for `./hello --flag1 --flag2 v2` to be interpreted as `--flag2` being the value to `flag1`, but intuitively this seems weird. I would assume that in most cases, a flag name is not a valid value for a flag.

Comment: If you think a flag name is not a valid value, you should check it from the code, the program can’t guess what the user meant. If he forget to add a value it’s on him, it’s like saying that you wrote 2 but meant to write 3.